# angularJs response array in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an API which is responding an array.And i would like to list with ng-repeat .

Here is the php Api code

```
    connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
    $sql = "SELECT id, First_Name, Last_time,Email,Phone_Number,Location,Phd_Degree,Phd_University,MS_Degree,MS_University,BS_Degree,BS_University FROM user";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $data=array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $data[]=array(
                'id'=>$row['id'],
                'First_Name'=>$row['First_Name'],
                'Last_time'=>$row['Last_time'],
                'Email'=>$row['Email'],
                'Phone_Number'=>$row['Phone_Number'],
                'Location'=>$row['Location'],
                'Phd_Degree'=>$row['Phd_Degree'],
                'Phd_University'=>$row['Phd_University'],
                'MS_Degree'=>$row['MS_Degree'],
                'MS_University'=>$row['MS_University'],
                'BS_Degree'=>$row['BS_Degree'],
                'BS_University'=>$row['BS_University']

           );

            //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["First_Name"]. " " . $row["Last_time"]. "
";
        }


    } else {
            $data[]=array(
                'message'=>'not success',
            );
        }

    print_r($data);
        //return $dat=json_encode($data);

    $conn->close();

?>
```

And here is my angular code .

```
    app.controller('listuser', function ($scope,$http,$log) {
            $scope.data=[];
            return $http({
                     method: 'POST',
                     url: 'apisource.php',


                })
                .then(function (results) {
                    $scope.data=results.data;
                    $log.log($scope.data);

                });

      });
```

Now the problem is when i am trying to implement on html it is not working

here is the html code

```
    
     

       {{x.First_Name}}
```

I think the problem is in my response as it is not in Json format but when i am trying to do json_encode() then in the response it is showing blank.

Here is here is the response showing in my console .

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [First_Name] => Zachary
            [Last_time] => Chatha
            [Email] => kouda@gmail.com
            [Phone_Number] => 7745752121
            [Location] => Guden�vej 1, 20 Vanl�se, Denmark, Apt 2
            [Phd_Degree] => test
            [Phd_University] => test
            [MS_Degree] => Master of Science in Pharmaceutical Sciences (MSPS)
            [MS_University] => Copenhagen University (Denmark)
            [BS_Degree] => \nBachelor of Science, Biological Applications and Technologies\n
            [BS_University] => University of Ioannina (Greece)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [First_Name] => Gaurav
            [Last_time] => Kumar
            [Email] => gtest@gmail.com
            [Phone_Number] => 7745752121
            [Location] => Guden�vej 1, 20 Vanl�se, Denmark, Apt 2
            [Phd_Degree] => test
            [Phd_University] => test
            [MS_Degree] => Master of Science in Pharmaceutical Sciences (MSPS)
            [MS_University] => Copenhagen University (Denmark)
            [BS_Degree] => \nBachelor of Science, Biological Applications and Technologies\n
            [BS_University] => University of Ioannina (Greece)
        )

)
```

Comment: Where's x coming from, is it inside a ng-repeat??

Comment: Yes it is inside ng-repeat="x in data" like this .@MaK

Comment: What are you getting in `results` in angular, Have the date sent from PHP side, json encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php print with json header, rather than returning:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: There must be some error in logic. Are you doing a 'echo'? There must be  some error in PHP file, please check by changing error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: As far as i can see there is no error it is just not being json_encoded().Yes i am using Echo .@Mahavir